# Dynamically created and filled table in JavaScript using Json array not working

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a table in JavaScript and fill it with the values of a JSON Array, but I can't manage to make it work. This is the code:

```
<script>

    var jArray = [
        {"name": "julio", "lastname":"Rodriguez","edad":33 },
        {"name": "maría", "lastname":"Díaz","edad":36 },
        {"name": "rosa", "lastname":"Rodriguez","edad":59 },
        {"name": "julio", "lastname":"Pereira","edad":68 }
    ]

    var t = document.createElement('table');
    t.style.border = '2px solid blue';
    var tb = document.createElement('tbody');
    t.appendChild(tb);

        for(i=0; i<jArray.length; i++){
            var r = document.createElement('tr');
            for(j=0; j<jArray[j].length; j++){

                r.style.border = '2px solid blue';

                for (var key in jArray[j]){
                    var c = document.createElement('td');
                    c.style.border = '1px solid black';
                    c.innerHTML = jArray[key]
                    r.appendChild(c)    
                    }
                tb.appendChild(r)
                }

            }
        t.appendChild(tb);

    document.body.appendChild(t);

</script>
```

Can you help me figure out what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Should only need two for loops, on for each "row" and another for each "column". You're loop over an additional level down which doesn't exist, hence no real DOM output. You should name the vars `tr` and `td` instead of `r` and `c`, otherwise it's just confusing. And also maybe use `recordIndex` and `propertyIndex` instead of `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more elegant to use the Array methods (better abstraction, no manual iteration), to append CSS rather than set style on each individual element, and to assign text to `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` (safer, faster):

```js
document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'))
  .textContent = `
table, tr {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
  `;
const jArray = [
  {"name": "julio", "lastname":"Rodriguez","edad":33 },
  {"name": "maría", "lastname":"Díaz","edad":36 },
  {"name": "rosa", "lastname":"Rodriguez","edad":59 },
  {"name": "julio", "lastname":"Pereira","edad":68 }
];
const table = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('table'));
const tbody = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'));
jArray.forEach((person) => {
  const tr = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
  Object.values(person).forEach((value) => (
    tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td')).textContent = value
  ));
});
```

Comment: Much nicer. There's a possibility OP has simplified example and maybe needs inline styles that are derived from some property on a person, otherwise CSS abstraction is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create 3 `for` loops, just 2.

And you need to use `jArray[i][key]` instead of `jArray[key]` to get value

```
var jArray = [
        {"name": "julio", "lastname":"Rodriguez","edad":33 },
        {"name": "maría", "lastname":"Díaz","edad":36 },
        {"name": "rosa", "lastname":"Rodriguez","edad":59 },
        {"name": "julio", "lastname":"Pereira","edad":68 }
    ]

    var t = document.createElement('table');
    t.style.border = '2px solid blue';
    var tb = document.createElement('tbody');
    t.appendChild(tb);

        for(var i=0; i<jArray.length; i++){
            var r = document.createElement('tr');

                r.style.border = '2px solid blue';

                for (var key in jArray[i]){
                    var c = document.createElement('td');
                    c.style.border = '1px solid black';
                    c.innerHTML = jArray[i][key]
                    r.appendChild(c)    
                    }
                tb.appendChild(r)

            }
        t.appendChild(tb);

    document.body.appendChild(t);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QrWWez